# Is the Java virtual machine machine dependent?

Tags: java, jvm

Is the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) platform dependent?

What is the advantage of using the JVM, and having Java be a translated language?

Comment: The JVM is platform-dependent.  At the very least the C code must be recompiled for each sufficiently different platform.  Java classes themselves (the "bytecodes" and the stuff around them) are platform-independent.  You have to try pretty hard to come up with a Java program that will run on one system and not another.

Comment: The compiler convert java program into bytecodes or .class file. Then job that convert the byte code into machine code by whom interpreter or JVM, otherwise JVM act as a interpreter, is it?

Comment: The JVM is an interpreter -- a "virtual machine".  And most modern JREs (Java runtime environments) include a JITC (just-in-time compiler) that dynamically converts the bytecodes of "hot" methods to machine code when the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally *a* JVM is platform dependent in the sense that it is implemented for the specific platform.

The advantage of using a JVM is that, at least in theory, it makes code written in Java platform agnostic and so the same code could run on any platform without modification to the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many advantages to having a virtual machine (such as the Java Virtual Machine - with its' write once, run anywhere promises); among them are -

1. Your application becomes operating system independent
2. Your application becomes architecture independent

In other words, your application becomes (at least somewhat) future-proof as regards to the shifting landscape of competitive vendors. Still (IMO) the biggest advantage is that Java applications and frameworks run the same on Linux, Mac and Windows. Although each does need it's own implementation of the Virtual Machine (e.g. the actual Java Runtime Environment is platform specific, it is available in [source form](http://openjdk.java.net/)).

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the JVM that dialogue with the operating system are platform dependant. But Java bytecode is independant, or at least supposed to be (edge cases probably exist).

The advantage of the JVM is simply to be able to compile once and be able to run executable bytecode on any platform which is supported. This is opposed to how things were before where you had to recompile to suit another OS or processor.

Btw, Java is not a translated/interpreted language like PHP or javascript. It's actually compiled with the JVM acting as a middleman or abstraction layer above an operating system.

Comment: Actually, the JVM provides both a bytecode interpreter AND a bytecode -> native code compiler.  And BOTH are typically used when you run a program.  (I know this is peripheral to the main point of your answer, but it is good to be factually accurate in your asides.)

Answer (score 0):

JVM itself is not independent. When you download jdk ,you can see that you have to choose you platform at first.You have to get clear your machine and OS type including unix-like ,windows or mac , 32-bit or 64-bit.But we always say that java is a platform-independent programming language,it is because JVM works as a middle-lays between your java application and the underline OS ,thus making java developer can just  focus on the same JVM  ,ignoring the isomerism of Operating Systems and hardware environments.