# JVM for different windows operating system

Tags: java, windows, jvm

As we know that the JVM implementation is OS specific (Windows / Linux / Solaris etc). I wanted to dig into deeper i.e., do we have different JVM implementations for different Windows OS versions?

Example:
Is JVM-Implementation-For-Win-XP same as JVM-Implementation-For-Win-8 ??

Answer (score 4):

> Is JVM-Implementation-For-Win-XP same as JVM-Implementation-For-Win-8 ??

Yes and no. They mostly use the same codebase, but there are some differences here and there. For example windows XP did not have a proper dualmode ipv4/ipv6 sockets, so there was - if I recall correctly - some special handling to use two native sockets per java NIO socket under XP, which is not necessary on newer windows versions.

But those differences are relatively small, they can be detected at runtime and the appropriate code paths can be used.

Your view of "implementations" is too monolithic, there may be separate implementations *for some components* without having separate implementations of the *JVM as a whole*.

There are many parts of the JVM shared across platforms.

There even is a project to have an easy-to-port subset of the JVM that's basically portable C/C++ and zero assembly, hence the name: [Project Zero](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/zero/)

Also note that the Oracle/OpenJDK Hotspot JVM [is not the only player in town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines).

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting from Oracle](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) , The JVM is same for all version of Windows, only the difference is architecture

*i.e 32-bit or 64-bit*.But they stopped providing guarantees for Windows-XP as

Microsoft stopped providing updates to it from  **April 8, 2014**.

Answer (score 0):

JVM is platform-independent. So that, the answer is yes. But as Arunesh's saying, the architecture is a little bit different.

Comment: Actually JVM is platform-dependent. '.class' file format is platform-independent. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157834/is-the-java-virtual-machine-machine-dependent and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120654/why-is-the-jvm-not-platform-independent-given-that-java-the-language-is-platf